# If you decrease the AC; does the room become cooler or hotter?

Tags: ambiguity

This happens with me many times. And people misinterpret it. But then I thought for a while and now think that I should have some unambiguous sentence to convey my message.

> Could you decrease the AC please? 
>   Sure, why not. 
>  Fifteen minutes later - Hey, it is chilling. Didn't you lower down the AC? 
>   I certainly did. It was 22 degrees and I made it 18! 
>   Ah, I mean decrease - make it less effective/intensive. The AC was too much.

Does increasing AC (Air Conditioning) means moving the degrees from 18 to 22 or 22 to 18? Both are right! The former is increase in AC as it's increasing in temperature and the latter one is correct in a way that it increased the intensity *(like, increase the volume, it's not audible).*

Comment: For the reason you mention – ambiguity – I wouldn't ask anyone to decrease the AC. Instead, I'd ask them to _raise the thermostat_.

Comment: Yes, I hate it when they install the thermostat too close to the floor!

Comment: @J.R. I'm afraid, nobody would understand that here! In fact, if I ask something to do with thermostat, they won't do anything thinking that it has nothing to do with the AC. Haha...the fact.

Comment: All joking aside, it's a [common idiom](https://www.google.com/search?q="raise+the+thermostat"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) in the U.S.

Comment: I don't think people here say *decrease*, but both *lower* and *turn down* seem fine to me.

Comment: @snailplane replacing 'decrease' with 'lower down' wont' make much difference. *Lower down* the AC - lower the temperature OR lower the intensity?

Comment: *Lower,* not *lower down*.  But yes, I was only talking about what sounds natural, not avoiding ambiguity--I wasn't answering the question, just commenting on it.

Comment: "Turn down the AC" = "turn down the intensity of the A/C" (and therefore raise the temperature). Of course, there's still some room for misinterpretation, but you can fix that problem by setting the context. _It's too cold in here; would you turn down the A/C?_ Problem solved.

Comment: @J.R. +1 Yes, that's the point. If I tell my problem and then tell whatever, it solves. It's **too cold** here, please decrease the AC (the intensity) will also convey the message.

Comment: Why not just say "Please lower (or raise) the temperature."? You cannot "reduce the AC" just like you cannot reduce a washing machine or a refrigerator.

Comment: @Happy you certainly can reduce/increase AC. That's because a washing machine or a refrigerator are the appliances, here, AC **also** means air conditioning!

Comment: Air conditioning, as the name suggests, can condition the air in a lot of ways, including altering the humidity, removing impurity, circulating air through the room at different fan speeds, and so on. (Read about it on Wikipedia.) "Reduce the AC" is ambiguous, but not just for the reason you cited. It could also mean reduce the humidity in the air or reduce the fan speed. Unless you specifically say that it is the temperature you want reduced, how could one tell? So no, you cannot "reduce" the AC.

Comment: @Happy Except that most air conditioning units do not have customer-accessible controls to set the humidity, fan speed, or level of pollen filtering. They just have a temperature dial. So if someone says "please reduce the AC", the only thing the other person can realistically do is change the temperature setting. If you were speaking to the HVAC technician, more specific instructions might be called for.

Comment: At EL&U: *[Does “turning down the air conditioning” make it warmer or colder?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103988)*

Comment: @Jay Most ACs at least have a setting to control the fan speed. I have also seen ACs with humidity control settings, in places with high humidity (such as places close to sea). Regardless of how many user-customizable settings are available, it doesn't take much effort to explicitly say 'temperature', so why not just do it and be done with it?

Comment: I used to work in an office where all ACs were operated from a centralized control room. If we were not comfortable with the AC setting, we would call the helpdesk and explicitly ask them to raise or lower the AC temperature. It creates no confusion and gets the job done. Honestly, I don't see what is the point of saying "reduce the AC" when (1) you know that this will lead to ambiguity and (2) you can easily state explicitly that you want the temperature lowered/raised.

Comment: @Happy (a) Easier to just say raise or lower the thermostat and avoid the ambiguity: Sure. (b) AC's have other controls, like fan speed: Well, my home's AC doesn't. I can turn it on or off, turn the fan to "auto" or "always on", and set the thermostat. That's it, and every house I've ever lived in, that's been it. Maybe wherever you live or the kinds of AC units you get are different. Well, I'm thinking of central air. Window AC units often have a fan speed.

Comment: So you see, 'raise/lower the temperature' works well in all the cases, but 'reduce the AC' works well only for "your type" of ACs. Life is too short to worry about special cases and figure out what's the "optimum" thing to say in each situation. Why not go with a sentence that works in 100% cases as against something that only works in 90% cases?

Comment: @Happy If we go with a sentence that works in 100% cases, why do we say **context** is important? Why do I write the whole scenario if I wanted a general answer? Had it been that case, I'd have asked 'How do I say someone to make room cooler!' We all **actually** give importance and ask for context but then while answering, we often get into *generalized* things especially when we see that the answer does not **match** our case and we think that our case is *general*.

Comment: @MaulikV Exactly what is the issue you have with saying 'Please lower/raise the AC temperature setting.' I only talked about general case because you guys were hell-bent on proving me wrong and wanted to use 'reduce the AC' no matter what even whether a better alternative is available.

Comment: I'm surprised at the hullabaloo. Sure, there are simple ways to make the statement less ambiguous, but I still think it's an interesting question from a language perspective. There are some situations where words like "up" and "down", or "increase" and "decrease", are hard to interpret. For example, Bill and Ted went golfing; Bill had a 79, Ted shot an 82. Who had the greater score? Personally, I think "decreasing the A/C" makes the room warmer, but I'll acknowledge that the ambiguity exists. There may be better ways to say it – but it's still a valid question, and I appreciate it.

Comment: _Can you **adjust** the a/c so that it is warmer in here?_ is unambiguous. And it is a phrase I use in real life, usually after just such an exchange as presented in the example. Most people in the South know that there is an ambiguity and potential confusion with the use of such words as increase/decrease, turn up/turn down.

Comment: @J.R. yeah, when I am not feeling well, I like to say I am feeling over par. Actually, I never say that, because it is dumb.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is of course that we are more used to heating systems than to cooling systems (heating is much easier, and humans have been doing it for tens of thousands of years).

And with every heating system, turning up the system means *increasing the resulting temperature*.

Many A/C systems have a temperature indication, and many even have buttons to increase or decrease the temperature. So effectively, when you mean "please **decrease** the effectiveness of the A/C", you are asking someone to press the **up**-arrow key on the A/C, **increasing** the temperature.

This is an contradictory thing for many people. When I turn up the heating, I increase the temperature. Now you want me to turn up the A/C, then I will likewise *increase* the temperature.

Strictly speaking, your interpretation makes sense (and as a stickler for literal interpretation, I have used it myself!). For most people, however, "turning up" any appliance that controls temperature means adjusting it in such a way that the *temperature* will increase.

There are examples where people mean the opposite of what they really say. Maybe the most common example is the confusing fact that electrical current runs in the *opposite* direction of the movement of the electrons.

Comment: A related example would be, "The milk is too warm, we need to turn ___ the refrigerator." Turn up, or turn down? Truth be told, I'm not sure which I'd say, particularly if the appliance had a knob like [this](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/CtQHFu_OyWo/hqdefault.jpg), where a higher number means a colder setting. Ovens are so much easier!

Comment: "The problem is of course that we are more used to heating systems than to cooling systems". Don't generalize to all humans based on your observations which seem to restricted to humans in the "cold countries". In a tropical country, such as the place where I live, cooling systems are much more common, and there is hardly ever any need for heating systems. People here who don't watch American movies, etc. don't even know about such systems.

Comment: @Happy: even so, heating systems have been used by humans for tens of thousands of years longer than _any_ adjustable cooling systems. I am well aware that there are many places where cooling systems are used now and where heating systems were never used much for rooms, but even there, heating systems have been used to prepare food. And if you increase your fire, the temperature in your oven or on your stove goes _up_, not _down_.

Comment: Yeah, but that has nothing to do with this question. When someone asks me to "reduce the AC", I don't think, "If I increase the fire, the temperature will go up in the oven, and humans have used heating systems for thousands of years, so obviously reduce the AC means reduce the temperature."

Comment: My point is that in all systems that we can think of "turning up or down" that regulate temperature, since before ewe started writing, "turning up" the appliance meant an increase in temperature. With the very very modern advent of _cooling_ appliances, we find ourselves struggling with "turning up" resulting in the _opposite_ effect. I think it has very much to do with this question, since the question illustrates _exactly_ that confusion. Everything that regulates temperature will create a higher temperature when turned up... oh noes, new inventions now!

Comment: I don't think the up/down issue requires extensive historical and psychological analysis. With a home heating system or an oven, you can interpret "turn it up" to mean "increase the temperature" or "increase the amount of work the appliance is doing", and the final result is the same. But for a cooling device, "increase the temperature" and "increase the amount of work it's doing" have opposite effects. So no ambiguity comes up in the first case but an ambiguity does come up in the second case. If we lived on a planet where no one ever invented home heating units or stoves, I think we'd ...

Comment: ... still have this ambiguity with cooling devices.

Comment: My wife went to a college where students regularly used underground utility tunnels to get between buildings. And in these tunnels were all sorts of pipes labeled, e.g. "water", with an arrow showing which way the water flowed, and "gas", with an arrow showing which way the gas flowed, and "laboratory vacuum", with an arrow showing ... Did the arrow point in the direction that they pumped the air out to create the vacuum? Or did it point in the direction that they pumped the vacuum to the laboratories?

Answer (score 0):

With a heating system, an oven, a fan, water flow, etc. to *turn up* or *increase* or *crank up* the setting is unambiguous -- you want **more** of whatever the thing is doing, which means raising the temperature or flow. To *turn down* or *decrease* the setting reduces activity (leading to a lower temperature, etc.).

With a cooling system, it is potentially ambiguous, as the *usual* meaning is still to increase the *activity*, but the result is to **lower** the temperature. Thus the convention (at least in the US) is "turn *up* the A/C" means to make it colder (lower temperature) by increasing the work the A/C unit is doing. In other countries and cultures, it could certainly instead mean "raise the temperature set point" (*decrease* the amount of cooling). If you're not sure how your request or statement is going to be taken by others, make sure it's unambiguous by stating the [undesirable] current condition and/or the desired results: "I'm cold, please turn down the A/C" or "Please turn down the A/C to raise the temperature" or even "Please turn *up* the temperature setting on the A/C".